# Connecting HTML drop down list to Flask

Tags: python, flask

Below is my HTML page:

```
<form action = "{{url_for('enter_ID')}}" method = "POST">
    <select name = "ID">
    <option value="ID1">Galactic_ID</option>
    <option value="ID2">Phone_ID</option>
    <option value="ID3">ident_ID</option>
      </select>                                                                                                                         
    ID:<input type = "text" name = "ID" />
       <input type='submit' value='Submit'>
```

below is my views.py:

```
from models1 import Customer,Phone,ID_Card
from flask import Flask, request, session, redirect, url_for, render_template, flash,json,jsonify
import os
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/',methods = ['GET','POST'])
def enter_ID():
if request.method == 'POST':
    Galactic_ID = request.form['ID']
    if Customer(Galactic_ID).find():
        data = Customer(Galactic_ID).Customer_relationships()
        return  render_template('dropdown.html',data=json.dumps(data))
    Phone_ID = request.form['ID']
    if Phone(Phone_ID).find():
        data = Phone(Phone_ID).Phone_relationships()
        return  render_template('dropdown.html',data=json.dumps(data))
    ident_ID = request.form['ID']
    if ID_Card(ident_ID).find():
        data = ID_Card(ident_ID).ID_Card_relationships()
        return  render_template('dropdown.html',data=json.dumps(data))

else:
    return render_template('dropdown.html')
```

I get the error:

```
      ValueError: View function did not return a response
```

My dropdown.html does have the necessary CSS and other details needed to render a d3.js graph. I have not found a standard way to connect the dropdown list to Flask. So , thought of posting it here.

Comment: It looks like function `enter_ID` does not always return something. BTW your indentation is completely messed-up, so it is hard to tell what it actually looks like. Please edit the question and use the preview to verify indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the request method is `POST`, but none of the filters trigger, no `return` statement is reached, and so `None` is returned, which is not a valid response.

Remove `else` before the last `render_template`.